# Change bar order and legend order in plot (matplotlib/pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to have the order of the legend and of the bars as the one defined in label_order

```
for feat in df.columns:
    label_order = ['Very Low', 'Low', 'Average', 'High', 'Very High']
    df.groupby('class')[feat].value_counts().unstack(0).plot.bar()
    plt.ylabel('Count')
    plt.xlabel('Score')
    plt.legend()
    plt.title('Answers to ' + str(feat) + ' divided for each risk class')
    plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vqF2.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of columns is determined by the column order in the dataframe you are plotting, therefore simply reordering the columns between unstacking and plotting will do the trick:

```py
df.groupby('class')[feat].value_counts().unstack(0)[label_order].plot.bar()
```

Here's a sample plot with and without the `[label_order]` addition

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can specify custom labels and handles in the axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

for feat in df.columns:

    label_order = ['Very Low', 'Low', 'Average', 'High', 'Very High']
    ax = df.groupby('class')[feat].value_counts().unstack(0).plot.bar()
    plt.ylabel('Count')
    plt.xlabel('Score')
    
    
    handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    dict_legends = dict(zip(labels, handles))

    handles_order =[dict_legends[lo] for lo in label_order]

    ax.legend(handles_order, label_order)

    
    plt.title('Answers to ' + str(feat) + ' divided for each risk class')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: df.groupby('class')[feat].value_counts().unstack(0)[label_order].plot.bar()

Adding this line, your code is exactly what I was looking for!